# fontspec: spaces in paths

Tags: fontspec, paths

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I am still not sure what the official or recommended policy is concerning `fontspec` and fonts with spaces in their path.

Example: I have a font with the following path `/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/E/Erasmus MMXVI/Erasmus MMXVI.otf`.

When I try to load this the following way, I get an error:

`\newfontfamily\erasmusfont{Erasmus MMXVI}[
Ligatures={TeX,Common},
Extension = .otf,
Path = /Users/simi/FontExplorerX/E/Erasmus MMXVI/]`

The only solution which works is renaming both the directory and the font name and removing all the spaces. This way, I everything works fine. I just don't think this is a clean solution.

**EDIT:** This with `LuaLaTeX` on macOS.

**EDIT 2:** The problem seems to be with fonts outside of the ordinary system paths. If I put the font in `~/Library/fonts/`, everything works fine. Of course, the whole point of the `Path` parameter is to access fonts in other locations.

Comment: Do you use XeTeX or LuaTeX? The reason I ask is that under Lua(La)TeX, it shouldn't be necessary to indicate a path unless the font hasn't been "installed", i.e., if it hasn't been made public to the system.

Comment: I use `LuaLaTeX` on `macOS`. And as you can see from my path, the font is not located in of the official font directories, but in a directory controlled by Linotype's FontExplorer X Pro.

Comment: I use MacOS and MacTeX as well. :-) What I tend to do whenever I download some commercial fonts is to (a) start up the `FontBook` app and (b) go to "File" -> "Add Fonts" and navigate to the directory in question. Once you click on the new fonts, there'll be a box in the lower-right corner of the window saying something like "Install Font"; click on that box. This'll make the fonts known to the entire operating system. (If you happen to use MS Word on your system as well, the fonts will now show up on its drop-down font men...) Finally, run `luaotfload-tool -f -u` to update the file cache.

Comment: (comment continued) If you don't run the `luaotfload-tool` utility, you may find that some extra time goes by the first time LuaLaTeX (actually, `luaotfload`) attempts to load the font. There may, of course, well be other ways to "install" new fonts and to make them known to the `luaotfload` utility, but the one I described above is reasonably simple and reliable.

Comment: As I said, I don't use `FontBook`  but `FontExplorer X Pro`. Therefore fonts are not stored in the usual path.

Comment: I have FontExplorer X Pro as well. :-) I've found, though, that it's not as reliable or straightforward as FontBook when it comes to making fonts known to the system. So, once in a while, I find I have to shut down FontExplorer -- because it complains bitterly about FontBook being open! -- and start up FontBook. Once I'm done with the font "initiation", I shut down FontBook and re-open FontExplorer...

Comment: AFAICS the problem are not the font managers per se, but the paths. The problem arises with fonts outside of the ordinary system paths. If I put the font in `~/Library/fonts/`, everything works fine. Of course, the whole point of the `Path` parameter is to access fonts in other locations.

Comment: Not sure if we're talking about different issues. Did you try out the suggestion I provided? Just curious.

Comment: The issue is not `FontBook` or `FontExplorer X` per se AFAICS. If you install a font with `FontBook`, it puts it in `~/Library/Fonts` and is then picked up by `LuaLaTeX`. Then spaces on the name don't seem to be a problem. But if you use a different path, then problems arise. Which begs the question how useful the `Path` parameter actually is.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized that FontBook "installs" fonts by copying them to `~/Library/Fonts`. Regarding the general usefulness of the `Path` parameter: It is my impression that spaces in file names and directory names are a thorny issue: Sometimes it's harmless to have such spaces and sometimes it's not. :-( In other words, it's still work in progress.

Comment: The year is 2022 and I'm facing a similar problem.